# Turning off NND.hotdeck Randomization in StatMatch?

Tags: r

I'm using NND.hotdeck from the StatMatch library, and discovered that running it on the same data produces different results every time.  Here's some demonstrative code:

```
library(StatMatch);
lab <- c(1:15, 51:65, 101:115);
iris.rec <- iris[lab, c(1:3,5)];
iris.don <- iris[-lab, c(1:2,4:5)];
a <- NND.hotdeck(data.rec=iris.rec, data.don=iris.don, match.vars=c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width") );
b <- NND.hotdeck(data.rec=iris.rec, data.don=iris.don, match.vars=c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width") );
View(a$mtc.ids)
View(b$mtc.ids)
```

The two grids are mostly identical, but there are differences.  I would expect them to be the same.

How can I turn off this randomization?  I found no reference to this behavior, much less a way to disable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with the package, but I am sure it uses random values somewhere.
You can set the random seed with `set.seed` before each call.

```
set.seed(1234)
a <- NND.hotdeck(data.rec=iris.rec, data.don=iris.don, match.vars=c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width"))
set.seed(1234)
b <- NND.hotdeck(data.rec=iris.rec, data.don=iris.don, match.vars=c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width"))
```

You can check if the two outputs are the same with:

```
all.equal(a, b)
```

It is not a very elegant solution maybe, and it does not turn off the randomization really, but it works.

Cheers,

alex

Comment: Doh!.  I assumed that the random number seed would be "stable" unless it was explicitly set to the timer.  Maybe it was elsewhere.  In any case, this worked.  I clicked to award the bounty, but it told me I could award it in 18 hours.  If this doesn't give you the bounty by Tuesday, I'll try again -- and feel free to nag me if I forget! :D

Comment: From ?NND.hotdeck: `When for a given recipient record there are more donors available at the minimum distance, one of them is picked at random.` Setting the random seed makes the random number generators return the same series of numbers. You can test that running: set.seed(1) rnorm(5) set.seed(1) rnorm(5)

Comment: Ah, just a tip. Semicolons are not needed at the end of each line. I suppose you are more used to matlab or c.

Comment: Thanks!  Although I know about setting the random seed, I'm used to languages where a stable seed is the default, so it never occurred to me to set it. Which brings me to the next point -- yep, I'm coming from a C++/Perl/PHP/JavaScript background, and it occasionally infiltrates my thinking.  Hey, at least I don't reach for loops in R :D